# printf is producing an unusual response

Tags: c, linux, printf, pointer-arithmetic

I am practicing Pointer Arithmetic but printf statement has a confusing response. My understandin says first 101 should be printed and then increment should occur. But here the problem goes...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[] = {101, 276, 345};
int *ptr = a;
printf ("%d\n%d\n", *ptr, *(++ptr) );
return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output

```
276
276
```

But, when I change the code to following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[] = {101, 276, 345};
int *ptr = a;
printf ("%d\n", *ptr);
return 0;
}
```

Result is following

```
101
```

Comment: My knowledge says the answer should be 101 276

Comment: Welcome to *Undefined Behavior* -  in `printf ("%d\n%d\n", *ptr, *(++ptr) );` the value of `ptr` is indeterminate as there is no defined order the parameters are evaluated in -- the order of evaluation is indeterminate. Is `++ptr` applied first or not? `printf ("%d\n%d\n", *a, *(++ptr) );` would be fine.

Comment: This has little to do with pointer arithmetic. You would have the same problem if you were printing integers like that.

Comment: Stop practicing 'clever' code where its behavior is difficult to understand at a glance.  Break it up into smaller steps, often using more temporary variables.

Answer (score 0):

++ptr changes the original pointer, try ptr + 1 instead of ++ptr

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[] = {101, 276, 345};
int *ptr = a;
printf ("%d\n%d\n", *ptr, *(ptr + 1) );
return 0;
}
```

---